Vectorized MD5 implemention in c# not returning the correct hash
I tried to implement md5 in c#, here is the code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

namespace md5vc
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector<uint>[] msg = new Vector<uint>[16];

            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                msg[i] = new Vector<uint>(0);
            }

            MD5.md5round(msg);

            Console.WriteLine("done... result :");
            Console.Write(MD5.a[0].ToString("x8") + MD5.b[0].ToString("x8") + MD5.c[0].ToString("x8") + MD5.d[0].ToString("x8"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class MD5
    {
        public static Vector<uint> K0xd76aa478 = new Vector<uint>(0xd76aa478);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xe8c7b756 = new Vector<uint>(0xe8c7b756);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x242070db = new Vector<uint>(0x242070db);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xc1bdceee = new Vector<uint>(0xc1bdceee);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xf57c0faf = new Vector<uint>(0xf57c0faf);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x4787c62a = new Vector<uint>(0x4787c62a);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xa8304613 = new Vector<uint>(0xa8304613);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfd469501 = new Vector<uint>(0xfd469501);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x698098d8 = new Vector<uint>(0x698098d8);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x8b44f7af = new Vector<uint>(0x8b44f7af);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xffff5bb1 = new Vector<uint>(0xffff5bb1);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x895cd7be = new Vector<uint>(0x895cd7be);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x6b901122 = new Vector<uint>(0x6b901122);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfd987193 = new Vector<uint>(0xfd987193);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xa679438e = new Vector<uint>(0xa679438e);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x49b40821 = new Vector<uint>(0x49b40821);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xf61e2562 = new Vector<uint>(0xf61e2562);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xc040b340 = new Vector<uint>(0xc040b340);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x265e5a51 = new Vector<uint>(0x265e5a51);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xe9b6c7aa = new Vector<uint>(0xe9b6c7aa);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xd62f105d = new Vector<uint>(0xd62f105d);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x02441453 = new Vector<uint>(0x02441453);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xd8a1e681 = new Vector<uint>(0xd8a1e681);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xe7d3fbc8 = new Vector<uint>(0xe7d3fbc8);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x21e1cde6 = new Vector<uint>(0x21e1cde6);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xc33707d6 = new Vector<uint>(0xc33707d6);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xf4d50d87 = new Vector<uint>(0xf4d50d87);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x455a14ed = new Vector<uint>(0x455a14ed);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xa9e3e905 = new Vector<uint>(0xa9e3e905);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfcefa3f8 = new Vector<uint>(0xfcefa3f8);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x676f02d9 = new Vector<uint>(0x676f02d9);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x8d2a4c8a = new Vector<uint>(0x8d2a4c8a);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfffa3942 = new Vector<uint>(0xfffa3942);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x8771f681 = new Vector<uint>(0x8771f681);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x6d9d6122 = new Vector<uint>(0x6d9d6122);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfde5380c = new Vector<uint>(0xfde5380c);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xa4beea44 = new Vector<uint>(0xa4beea44);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x4bdecfa9 = new Vector<uint>(0x4bdecfa9);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xf6bb4b60 = new Vector<uint>(0xf6bb4b60);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xbebfbc70 = new Vector<uint>(0xbebfbc70);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x289b7ec6 = new Vector<uint>(0x289b7ec6);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xeaa127fa = new Vector<uint>(0xeaa127fa);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xd4ef3085 = new Vector<uint>(0xd4ef3085);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x04881d05 = new Vector<uint>(0x04881d05);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xd9d4d039 = new Vector<uint>(0xd9d4d039);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xe6db99e5 = new Vector<uint>(0xe6db99e5);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x1fa27cf8 = new Vector<uint>(0x1fa27cf8);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xc4ac5665 = new Vector<uint>(0xc4ac5665);

        public static Vector<uint> K0xf4292244 = new Vector<uint>(0xf4292244);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x432aff97 = new Vector<uint>(0x432aff97);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xab9423a7 = new Vector<uint>(0xab9423a7);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfc93a039 = new Vector<uint>(0xfc93a039);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x655b59c3 = new Vector<uint>(0x655b59c3);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x8f0ccc92 = new Vector<uint>(0x8f0ccc92);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xffeff47d = new Vector<uint>(0xffeff47d);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x85845dd1 = new Vector<uint>(0x85845dd1);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x6fa87e4f = new Vector<uint>(0x6fa87e4f);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xfe2ce6e0 = new Vector<uint>(0xfe2ce6e0);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xa3014314 = new Vector<uint>(0xa3014314);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x4e0811a1 = new Vector<uint>(0x4e0811a1);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xf7537e82 = new Vector<uint>(0xf7537e82);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xbd3af235 = new Vector<uint>(0xbd3af235);
        public static Vector<uint> K0x2ad7d2bb = new Vector<uint>(0x2ad7d2bb);
        public static Vector<uint> K0xeb86d391 = new Vector<uint>(0xeb86d391);

        public static Vector<uint> a = new Vector<uint>(0x67452301);
        public static Vector<uint> b = new Vector<uint>(0xefcdab89);
        public static Vector<uint> c = new Vector<uint>(0x98badcfe);
        public static Vector<uint> d = new Vector<uint>(0x10325476);


        public static int[] s = new int[64]
        {
            7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,
            5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,
            4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,
            6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21
        };


        public static void md5round(Vector<uint>[] msg)
        {
            Vector<uint> A = new Vector<uint>(0x67452301);
            Vector<uint> B = new Vector<uint>(0xefcdab89);
            Vector<uint> C = new Vector<uint>(0x98badcfe);
            Vector<uint> D = new Vector<uint>(0x10325476);


            step(F, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[0], K0xd76aa478, s[0]);
            step(F, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[1], K0xe8c7b756, s[1]);
            step(F, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[2], K0x242070db, s[2]);
            step(F, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[3], K0xc1bdceee, s[3]);
            step(F, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[4], K0xf57c0faf, s[4]);
            step(F, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[5], K0x4787c62a, s[5]);
            step(F, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[6], K0xa8304613, s[6]);
            step(F, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[7], K0xfd469501, s[7]);
            step(F, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[8], K0x698098d8, s[8]);
            step(F, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[9], K0x8b44f7af, s[9]);
            step(F, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[10], K0xffff5bb1, s[10]);
            step(F, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[11], K0x895cd7be, s[11]);
            step(F, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[12], K0x6b901122, s[12]);
            step(F, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[13], K0xfd987193, s[13]);
            step(F, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[14], K0xa679438e, s[14]);
            step(F, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[15], K0x49b40821, s[15]);

            step(G, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[1], K0xf61e2562, s[16]);
            step(G, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[6], K0xc040b340, s[17]);
            step(G, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[11], K0x265e5a51, s[18]);
            step(G, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[0], K0xe9b6c7aa, s[19]);
            step(G, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[5], K0xd62f105d, s[20]);
            step(G, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[10], K0x02441453, s[21]);
            step(G, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[15], K0xd8a1e681, s[22]);
            step(G, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[4], K0xe7d3fbc8, s[23]);
            step(G, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[9], K0x21e1cde6, s[24]);
            step(G, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[14], K0xc33707d6, s[25]);
            step(G, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[3], K0xf4d50d87, s[26]);
            step(G, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[8], K0x455a14ed, s[27]);
            step(G, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[13], K0xa9e3e905, s[28]);
            step(G, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[2], K0xfcefa3f8, s[29]);
            step(G, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[7], K0x676f02d9, s[30]);
            step(G, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[12], K0x8d2a4c8a, s[31]);

            step(H, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[5], K0xfffa3942, s[32]);
            step(H, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[8], K0x8771f681, s[33]);
            step(H, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[11], K0x6d9d6122, s[34]);
            step(H, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[14], K0xfde5380c, s[35]);
            step(H, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[1], K0xa4beea44, s[36]);
            step(H, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[4], K0x4bdecfa9, s[37]);
            step(H, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[7], K0xf6bb4b60, s[38]);
            step(H, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[10], K0xbebfbc70, s[39]);
            step(H, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[13], K0x289b7ec6, s[40]);
            step(H, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[0], K0xeaa127fa, s[41]);
            step(H, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[3], K0xd4ef3085, s[42]);
            step(H, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[6], K0x04881d05, s[43]);
            step(H, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[9], K0xd9d4d039, s[44]);
            step(H, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[12], K0xe6db99e5, s[45]);
            step(H, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[15], K0x1fa27cf8, s[46]);
            step(H, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[2], K0xc4ac5665, s[47]);

            step(I, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[0], K0xf4292244, s[48]);
            step(I, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[7], K0x432aff97, s[49]);
            step(I, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[14], K0xab9423a7, s[50]);
            step(I, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[5], K0xfc93a039, s[51]);
            step(I, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[12], K0x655b59c3, s[52]);
            step(I, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[3], K0x8f0ccc92, s[53]);
            step(I, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[10], K0xffeff47d, s[54]);
            step(I, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[1], K0x85845dd1, s[55]);
            step(I, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[8], K0x6fa87e4f, s[56]);
            step(I, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[15], K0xfe2ce6e0, s[57]);
            step(I, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[6], K0xa3014314, s[58]);
            step(I, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[13], K0x4e0811a1, s[59]);
            step(I, ref A, ref B, ref C, ref D, msg[4], K0xf7537e82, s[60]);
            step(I, ref D, ref A, ref B, ref C, msg[11], K0xbd3af235, s[61]);
            step(I, ref C, ref D, ref A, ref B, msg[2], K0x2ad7d2bb, s[62]);
            step(I, ref B, ref C, ref D, ref A, msg[9], K0xeb86d391, s[63]);


            a = Vector.Add(a, A);
            b = Vector.Add(b, B);
            c = Vector.Add(c, C);
            d = Vector.Add(d, D);

        }

        public static void step(Func<Vector<uint>, Vector<uint>, Vector<uint>, Vector<uint>> f, 
            ref Vector<uint> a, ref Vector<uint> b, ref Vector<uint> c, ref Vector<uint> d, Vector<uint> x, Vector<uint> t, int s)
        {
            a = Vector.Add(a, f(b, c, d));
            a = Vector.Add(a, x);
            a = Vector.Add(a, t);

            a = rotl(a, s);
            a = Vector.Add(a, b);
        }

        public static Vector<uint> rotl(Vector<uint> x, int s)
        {
            uint rotatedValue = (x[0] << s) | (x[0] >> (32 - s));
            return new Vector<uint>(rotatedValue);
        }

        public static Vector<uint> F(Vector<uint>b, Vector<uint> c, Vector<uint> d)
        {
            Vector<uint> temp = Vector.BitwiseOr(Vector.BitwiseAnd(b, c), Vector.AndNot(b, d));
            return temp;
        }

        public static Vector<uint> G(Vector<uint> b, Vector<uint> c, Vector<uint> d)
        {
            Vector<uint> temp = Vector.BitwiseOr(Vector.BitwiseAnd(d, b), Vector.AndNot(d, c));
            return temp;
        }

        public static Vector<uint> H(Vector<uint> b, Vector<uint> c, Vector<uint> d)
        {
            Vector<uint> temp = Vector.Xor(b, Vector.Xor(c, d));
            return temp;
        }

        public static Vector<uint> I(Vector<uint> b, Vector<uint> c, Vector<uint> d)
        {
            Vector<uint> temp = Vector.Xor(c, Vector.BitwiseOr(b, ~d));
            return temp;
        }

    }
}

I have checked the K constants, and they are all the same as in the MD5 standard. I have checked the step function, but that also should work fine. I don't know where the problem is.
I implemented on based on SimonGoater's implemention: https://github.com/FastAsChuff/MD5-SIMD-Test/blob/main/md5simdtest3.c
When I set all the message blocks to zero, in the main function, the code returns f420b6f76bf128bc8251435b7b28313d which is not the MD5 hash of the infamous zero input, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
I don't know where the problem is.

Though not a valid input message, for all zeroes I get ac1d1f03d08ea56eb767ab1f91773174.

Have you run the code in the debugger to see what's going on? If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is the perfect time to learn.
